# How to change WHERE NOT EXISTS to ANY?

Tags: sql, where-clause, any

How can I change this following code from WHERE NOT EXISTS to ANY

```
SELECT
    CategoryName
FROM 
    Categories
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM Products
                WHERE Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID)
```

My goal was to show which category names have no products associated with them. Please comment if you need a schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use `any` then just negate it with `not`

```
select CategoryName
FROM Categories
where not (categoryId = any (select CategoryId from products))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd, but you can use `ALL` instead of `ANY`:

```
select c.*
from categories c
where categoryID <> all (select p.categoryID from products p)
```

Comment: I have to change it to an ANY clause. I cant use the ALL.